# Best way to make a single Play Framework 2.6 action handle a route disregarding its HTTP method

Tags: java, playframework

We have a Play 2.6 Java application that works great so far.
Now we need to add some route to it that will just be taking the original request, decorating it with some additional headers or whatever and sending it forward to be handled by some other app (probably using Play's WS client)
The question is if it is possible to create some route like this one in the Play routes file:

`*   /forward-to-smth/*whatever   my.Action.forward`

where * will match all the HTTP Methods, and we'll be just getting the Http.Request instance in the action body and handling it as required.

What is the best way of handling this kind of scenarios in Play?
We can probably create multiple routes' entries for each HTTP method and multiple actions in in the controller for each of the methods, delegating all the handling to a single handle-it-all method, but is there any more elegant solution?

Creating some custom **HttpRequestHandler** for this case will probably be an overkill?

Comment: I am facing a similar issue right now, did you find a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Play conveniently generates a Router from the routes file, but you can also write a router yourself. See https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaSirdRouter

```
class MyRouter @Inject()(controller: MyController) extends SimpleRouter {
  override def routes: Routes = {
    case _ => controller.forward
  }
}
```

Then, in your routes file, add

```
-> /forward-to-smth  my.MyRouter
```

Comment: thank you for your response, but as I mentioned above, we are using the Java version of the Play Framework. There is no SirdRouter there. Just this: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaRoutingDsl
And as far as I remember - there was no way to make it play together with the routes file we already have

Comment: Ah, sorry. I missed this detail. I bet it's still possible to do this, but cannot be of much help.